# Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-p}f(nx)$ converges absolutely a.e. iff $p>1-d$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I need some help to solve this problem
Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\int |f|>0$. Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-p}f(nx)$ converges absolutely a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^d$ if and only if $p>1-d$.
Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint for the if-direction: Use the monotone convergence theorem and change variables. This argument will also show that the series converges in $L^1$, if and only if $p> 1-d$.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to prove the "only if" direction.